# How to disable windows effects in 13.04?

Tags: compiz, 13.04, window, effects

New install of 13.04 on a thinkpad x230.  I want to disable the windows effects (they sort of zoom in and out from the middle of the screen).  I find it distracting.  I tried downloading the compizConfig Settings Manager and un-checking "Animations", "Fading Windows" and "Window Decoration".  But nothing changed.  Is there another way to lose these effects?

Comment: Look around in the unity tweak tool `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`, there may be settings to disable effects.

Comment: Good advice generally, but I've checked Ubuntu tweak and not found anything for this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the window snapping feature?

As @Yet Another User said, install unity-tweak-tool (not ubuntu tweak) from software center or by command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then launch it, disable it by Window Manager -> Window Snapping:

[image]